# Determining distinct clusters with Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a cypher query that returns a series of paths, which are partly overlapping and result in a number of distinct clusters. In this case there will be a modest number of clusters (100 - 1000) of relatively small size (1-50 nodes). The complete dataset is typically a few million nodes (the query extracts a relatively small subset of the total nodes).

A simplified version of the query looks like this:

```
MATCH p=(a:M)-[:F2EDGE]-(b:M) WHERE a.prop > 90 AND b.prop > 90 RETURN p
```

The actual query would be a bit more complex than that with a variable number of intermediate nodes, but that should exemplify the problem.

Now I want to explore the different clusters that are generated by that query.
I have found the docs on the [Connected Components algorithm](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/algorithms/connected-components/) which seems on the right lines, but I can't see how that can be applied to a list of paths that is the result of the query.
I would want to be able to:

1. get list of the clusters and some basic properties for then (e.g. number of nodes)
2. fetch data that allowed me to reproducibly fetch that cluster again in the future (maybe by fetching the node ids or by adding new "cluster" nodes that linked to each cluster)

Can someone suggest how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [cypher projections](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/introduction/#cypher-projection) with that

something along these lines:

```
CALL algo.unionFind('
MATCH (a:M) WHERE a.prop > 90 RETURN id(a) as id
UNION
MATCH (b:M) AND b.prop > 90 RETURN id(b) as id
', '
MATCH p=(a:M)-[:F2EDGE]->(b:M) WHERE a.prop > 90 AND b.prop > 90 RETURN id(a) as source, id(b) as target
', {graph:"cypher",write:true, partitionProperty:"partition"})
```

Please note that in this case one of the node queries would have been enough as they both have the same criteria, I just wanted to demonstrate how to combine queries on source and target nodes.

If you want to restrict the nodes to **only the ones** in your connected graph you can also use this as "node-query":

```
MATCH (a:M)-[:F2EDGE]-(b:M) 
WHERE a.prop > 90 AND b.prop > 90 
UNWIND [id(a), id(b)] as id
RETURN distinct id
```